# Установка будильника срабатывающего каждый день

Tags: java, android

Стоит цель сделать функцию повтора у будильника по дням(пн,вт,ср,чт,пт,сб,вс,каж.день). Решил сделать тест, присылать уведомления с интервалом в день, и тут появились проблемы.

```
  AlarmManager alarmManager;
Calendar calendar;
AlarmReceiver receiver;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    receiver = new AlarmReceiver();
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);


    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,new Random().nextInt(100)+1,new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class),0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

}
```

В последней строчке стоит интервал один день, а срабатывает один раз в 2 дня и может сработать в неточное время. Почитал, что с API 19+ `setRepeating()` стал `inexact`. Что же использовать для точной работы повторений будильника?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime,
            24*60*60*1000, pi);
```

где интервал задан вручную.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но проблема уже давно решена, посмотрите дату вопроса)

Comment: @DenisZinkovskiy Ответы на этом ресурсе не лично для вас, а для сообщества в целом, чтобы люди, столкнувшиеся с аналогичной проблемой могли решить ее. Если вы нашли решение самостоятельно, оформите его ответом, это поможет другим людям решить аналогичную проблему.